# sprintf trouble

Tags: string

```
char cTime[22];

sprintf(cTime, "%04s/%02s/%2s:%02s:%02s:%02s", year(), month(), day(), hour(), minute(), second());
```

This `sprintf` line causes this error:**B0100000063f694Š

Could someone help me debug this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*%s* is string macro but output of *year(),...* is probably an integer type. Use *%d* or *%u* macros in format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - try making each of the %-specifiers match the kind of conversion you want for each variable in the rest of the call. F/ex, %d converts an integer to a string in decimal radix, %f converts a double to a number with a decimal fraction, etc. In all cases, the output will be as characters; you don't need to specify that.